# How to bundle multiple transactions in one on Ethereum using web3.py?

Tags: python, ethereum, smartcontracts, web3py, uniswap

I'm trying to use Python to make multiple swaps in one transaction on Uniswap (swaping ETH against the token).

I successfully wrote a Python function that does just that, using swapExactETHForTokens from the Uniswap v2 router (web3 has been instantiated before that):

```
def buyToken(token_to_buy, eth_amount):
    token_to_buy = web3.to_checksum_address(token_to_buy)
    token_to_spend = web3.to_checksum_address(chain_token)

    contract = web3.eth.contract(address=Web3.to_checksum_address(uni_v2_router_address), abi=uni_v2_router_abi)

    nonce = web3.eth.get_transaction_count(wallet_address)

    call_function = contract.functions.swapExactETHForTokens(
        0,
        [token_to_spend, token_to_buy],
        wallet_address,
        (int(time.time()) + 600)
    ).build_transaction({
        'from': wallet_address,
        'value': web3.to_wei(eth_amount,'ether'),
        'nonce': nonce,
    })

    signed_txn = web3.eth.account.sign_transaction(call_function, private_key=wallet_private_key)
    tx_token = web3.eth.send_raw_transaction(signed_txn.rawTransaction)
    return web3.to_hex(tx_token)
```

So far so good.
Now I'd like to buy tokens in small amounts in multiple transactions. This would result in me sending and paying gas for multiple transactions, which is why I want to bundle them in one transaction.
I'm not sure what would be the best way to go about it, or if it's even possible using Python.
I considered using the Multicall3 contract (https://www.multicall3.com/), but I can't find any documentation or example on how to use it with raw transactions.

There's also a multicall function in the Uniswap v3 router, but if it would be easier to implement in my code

I'll also later need to send the token to a few different wallets, so it would be great if the solution could be expanded so that I could do that in one transaction as well. Thanks!

Comment: The way I see it, your options are use the multicall3 contract, uniswap's multicall, or to deploy your own contract that can execute predefined logic via a simple function call from an EOA.

Answer (score 0):

> So far so good. Now I'd like to buy tokens in small amounts in multiple transactions. This would result in me sending and paying gas for multiple transactions, which is why I want to bundle them in one transaction.

For bundling multiple state-modifying smart contract calls in a single transaction you need to write your own smart contract to do this.

Multicall is only for optimising reading the chain state.